# How can I integrate FCKeditor in a Zend Framework application?

Tags: zend-framework, fckeditor, rte

I've seen there are questions here about how to integrate scripts in ZF. There are also some questions about FCKEditor. But I have found nothing about both ZF and FCKEditor.
Does anyone use FCKEditor with ZF? 
Alternatively...is there an RTE which can integrate well with ZF?

Thank you

Comment: Glups! You're right there, iraklis.

Comment: P.S. you should look at CKEditor too (the new version) http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 2):

Hi there is a some pages that may be usefull:

---

http://blog.ekini.net/2007/11/28/using-fckeditor-with-zend-framework-file-browser-enabled/
http://www.leftcolumn.net/2009/03/10/zend-framework-how-to-add-fckeditor-to-a-zend_form/
http://vnwds.com/threads/20-Build-FCKeditor-in-your-Zend-Project-with-Zend_View_Helper

Comment: Thanks Behrang. I have looked at the second link since I posted the question but I didn' know of the other two.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably want to create zend form elements and a zend view helper. It would enable seamless zend framwork integration and can be reused to reduce any code duplication.

Here's an article explaining how:

[FCKeditor Zend Form Integration](http://www.websitefactors.co.uk/zend-framework/2011/05/fckeditor-zend-form-integration/)